# Disable automatic indexing in sql server

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I need to disable auto indexing in a SQL Server database, basically I want to control when the indexing occurs (for example, at night).

I don't want to disable the indexes by table, for instance like:

```
ALTER INDEX [IX_NAME] ON SCHEMA.TABLE DISABLE
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: What sort of auto-indexing are you talking about?

Comment: You can disable an index - but then it's never used (and also never updated). If your index is enabled, i.e. used for speeding up queries, you **cannot** turn off the automatic index maintenance. This is SQL Server - it does this for you, it's not like in dBase days where it's your burden to update the indices manually.

Comment: That is exactly what I want... I believe Oracle supports it too.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable an index as outlined [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177406.aspx), but then it won't be used to query data until you re-enable it.  You can't disable an index and still have it used in queries- such a thing could result in incorrect or inconsistent results.

Comment: You are right, but that's not an escuse I believe. In Oracle you can specify when to rebuild your indexes. It's not hard to keep track if the engine should use the index or not. It just has to mark it as corrupted or something like that...

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the Oracle documentation on that.  I have a hard time believing that it supports indices which are both queryable and have delayed rebuild.

Comment: Closest I can think of is that Oracle has support for refreshing materialized views on demand. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/refresh.htm#DWHSG015 SQL Server, to my knowledge, does not for its indexed views.